# Only run once http request

Tags: angularjs, http

I am making AngularJS app, and I am making http post request on the controllers of some views, but I only want it to run once. I tried doing this.

```
aldro_app.controller('ctrInicio', function ($scope,$http, $rootScope) {

var contadorInicioCtr = 0;
contadorInicioCtr++;
 console.log("Contador -> " + contadorInicioCtr );
/* Http para retirar las ultimas facturas del contrato */
 var id = parseInt(getVariable("idcontrato"));
 var url = "http://api/url";
 if (contadorInicioCtr===1){
 $http({
     url : url,
     method: "POST",
     data: {id_contrato: id},
     headers:{
     "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8",
     "Authorization": "Bearer " + getVariable("token")
  }
 })
  .then(function(response){
       setVariable("facturas" , JSON.stringify(response.data));
 })
 }
});
```

I tried with a simple counter, but when I change to another view and come back to the view of ctrInicio, the counter stays at 1, so what can I do to only run `HTTP` once?

Comment: it's because you are resetting it back to 0 with `contadorInicioCtr = 0`. It would be better if you can describe what you want to accomplish

Comment: Just to execute the http one time, the objecitve of the counter is to check if I am l loading the controller for second time, if its so, then the http shouldnt happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because everytime you visit your page, scope is reinitialized. And all the values set in the previous scope are set to default.

What you can do to achieve what you want is to set a flag on `rootScope`.

Inside your controller, Something like

```
$rootScope.contadorInicioCtr++
```

And add a check on

```
if ( $rootScope.contadorInicioCtr===1){ ... }
```

Another approach can be

Create a service for sending your requests and update a flag when first time request has been sent. Now you can check for that flag before sending the request.

As `service` in angular is singleton, this won't update the value of the variable and do that all for you.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: This works for me now, Iam gonna try doing a `service`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to know that. Consider upvoting the answer :)